# Find vertices of a hypercube given a set of partitions

Tags: mesh, partitions

### Problem

The goal is to take a set of $n$ linear partitions $\left\{p_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{n}$ and create a hypercubic partition:

$$
\mathbf{P}=p_{1}\times p_{2}\times \cdots\times p_{n}
$$

Each partition $p$ has a know length $m_{k}$, ${k=1,n}$.

In practice $n>10^{6}$.

### Example:

#### Input

Let $n=4$ and the partition set consists of $p_1=(x_1,\dots,x_{m_1})$, $p_2=(y_1, \dots, y_{m_2})$, $P_3=(z_1,\dots,z_{m_3})$, and $p_4=(t_1,\dots,t_{m_4})$.

#### Output

The $\prod_{k=1}^{n}m_{k} \times n$ array containing the vertices of the hypercubic mesh:
$$ \bf{A} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
%
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & t_1 \\
%
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & t_2 \\
%
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & \vdots \\
%
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & t_{m_{4}} \\
%
x_1 & y_1 & z_2 & t_1 \\
%
x_1 & y_1 & z_2 & \vdots \\
%
x_1 & y_1 & z_2 & t_{m_{4}} \\
%
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
%
x_{m_{1}} & y_{m_{2}} & z_{m_{3}} & t_{m_{4}} \\
%
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: [Tuples](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tuples.html)?

Comment: @kglr. Bingo! $A=$Tuples[$p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$]. If you submit a formal answer I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p1 = Array[Subscript[x, #] &, {2}];
p2 = Array[Subscript[y, #] &, {3}];
p3 = Array[Subscript[z, #] &, {2}];
p4 = Array[Subscript[t, #] &, {2}];
Tuples[{p1, p2, p3, p4}] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & t_1 \\
>  x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & t_2 \\
>  x_1 & y_1 & z_2 & t_1 \\
>  x_1 & y_1 & z_2 & t_2 \\
>  x_1 & y_2 & z_1 & t_1 \\
>  x_1 & y_2 & z_1 & t_2 \\
>  x_1 & y_2 & z_2 & t_1 \\
>  x_1 & y_2 & z_2 & t_2 \\
>  x_1 & y_3 & z_1 & t_1 \\
>  x_1 & y_3 & z_1 & t_2 \\
>  x_1 & y_3 & z_2 & t_1 \\
>  x_1 & y_3 & z_2 & t_2 \\
>  x_2 & y_1 & z_1 & t_1 \\
>  x_2 & y_1 & z_1 & t_2 \\
>  x_2 & y_1 & z_2 & t_1 \\
>  x_2 & y_1 & z_2 & t_2 \\
>  x_2 & y_2 & z_1 & t_1 \\
>  x_2 & y_2 & z_1 & t_2 \\
>  x_2 & y_2 & z_2 & t_1 \\
>  x_2 & y_2 & z_2 & t_2 \\
>  x_2 & y_3 & z_1 & t_1 \\
>  x_2 & y_3 & z_1 & t_2 \\
>  x_2 & y_3 & z_2 & t_1 \\
>  x_2 & y_3 & z_2 & t_2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: ... just hope that $n>10^6$ is a typo:)